# error browsing directory under ADLS Gen2 container for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am creating a dataset in Azure Data Factory.  This dataset will be a Parquet file within a directory under a certain container in an ADLS Gen2 account.  The container name is 'raw', and the directory that I want to place the file into is source/system1/FullLoad.  When I click on Browse next to File path, I am able to access the container, but I cannot access the directory.  When I hit folder 'source', I get the error shown below.

How can I drill to the desired directory?  As the error message indicates, I suspect that it's something to do with permissions to access the data (the Parquet file doesn't exist yet, as it will be used as a sink in a copy activity that hasn't been run yet), but I don't know how to resolve.

[image]

Comment: Can you check if you have storage data blob contributor access to the directories inside your raw container? You can check it from azure portal, go to your storage account, navigate to the container and then directory, click on Access Control on the left panel and check role assignment. The user or managed identity you are using for your data factory should have storage data blob contributor access on the storage account.

Comment: That was the issue.  The managed identity had contributor access, but not storage blob contributor access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for confirming putting the resolution for others if anyone face this issue.
The user or managed identity you are using for your data factory should have storage data blob contributor access on the storage account. You can check it from azure portal, go to your storage account, navigate to the container and then directory, click on Access Control on the left panel and check role assignment. If it is missing add the role assignment of storage data blob contributor to your managed identity.